# Bubble sort on linked list

Tags: c, sorting, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to write an implementation of bubble sort to sort a linked list, but at the moment it's causing my program to crash.

Here's how the structures are defined:

```
typedef struct shopping_cart cart;
struct shopping_cart{
    char *item_name;
    int quantity;
    cart *next;
};
```

And here's my code:

```
void sort(cart *head){
    cart *i, *j;
    cart *second = get_second(head);
    cart *last = get_end_of_cart(head);

    for(i = second; i != NULL; i = i->next){
        for(j = head; j != last; j = j->next){
            if ((compare(j, j->next) > 0)){
                swap(j, j->next);
            }
        }
    }
}

void swap(cart *ptr1, cart *ptr2){
    cart *temp;
    temp = ptr1;
    ptr1 = ptr2;
    ptr2 = temp;
}

cart *get_end_of_cart(cart *head){
    cart *_next = head;

    while (_next->next != NULL){
        _next = _next->next;
    }

    return _next;
}


cart *get_second(cart *head){
    cart *first_item = head;
    cart *second_item = first_item->next;
    return second_item;
}
```

The `compare` function definitely works, so I won't post it here. I'm pretty sure `get_second` and `get_end_of_cart` also work. So I guess my error is either in `swap` or `sort`, but I can't see where the issue is.

Comment: Your swap function doesn't do anything.  It is swapping local variables.

Comment: Your swap method doesn't work at all. You need to pass by reference, and then actually update links to previous/next items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you swap function

```
void swap(cart **ptr1, cart **ptr2){
    cart *temp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;
}
```

What you do is passing a pointer and change its value locally. You need to pass the address of the pointer (pointer to a pointer) instead.

**Make sure** where you use the `swap` function, the arguments are the addresses of the `cart` pointers.

Here is a snippet:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cart *i = (cart *)malloc(sizeof(cart));
    cart *j = (cart *)malloc(sizeof(cart));
    i->item_name = "hello";
    j->item_name =" bla";
    i->next = j;
    printf("i %s\n", i->item_name);
    printf("j %s\n", j->item_name);
    swap(&i, &j);
    printf("i %s\n", i->item_name);
    printf("j %s\n", j->item_name);
}
```

The output should be:

```
i hello
j  bla
i  bla
j hello
```

### EDIT

However, in your case, that won't work, because the addresses are changed and this may cause segmentation fault at the worst case.
A different way to tackle this is to swap the attributes.

```
void swap(cart *ptr1, cart *ptr2){
    char *tmp_name;
    int tmp_quantity;
    tmp_name = ptr1->item_name;
    tmp_quantity = ptr1->quantity;
    ptr1->item_name = ptr2->item_name;
    ptr1->quantity = ptr2->quantity;
    ptr2->item_name = tmp_name;
    ptr2->quantity = tmp_quantity;
}
```

Now, we won't have to handle the `next` and hope for the best. We just swapping between `i`'s and `j`'s attributes (`item_name` and `quantity`).

So the snippet should look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cart *i = (cart *)malloc(sizeof(cart));
    cart *j = (cart *)malloc(sizeof(cart));
    i->item_name = "hello";
    j->item_name =" bla";
    i->next = j;
    printf("i %s\n", i->item_name);
    printf("j %s\n", j->item_name);
    swap(i, i->next);
    printf("i %s\n", i->item_name);
    printf("j %s\n", j->item_name);
}
```

Tada! :D

Comment: This gives me following error: `warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap' from incompatible pointer
type [enabled by default]
                 swap(j, j->next);
                 ^
note: expected 'struct cart **' but argument is of type 'struct c
art *'
 void swap(cart **ptr1, cart **ptr2);`

Comment: Yeah, that's right. You need to change `swap(j, j->next)` into `swap(&j, &j->next)` as I have mentioned above :)

Comment: Hmm, it still seems to not be working. I get what seems to be an infinite loop when I try to print out the result of the sorting.

Comment: Yeah, compiles fine, and I don't get any crashes or weird behaviour. Except, when I print the list after sorting, it prints in the same order as the input. So it seems like no sorting was done at all. Also, I checked and double checked my compare function - it's definitely working fine, so it cant be that.

Comment: I think it might be because the previous item of the linked list is still pointing to the original item (even after its been swapped) and thats why this is happening. Do you think this is correct? Because I'm trying to print like this: `_next = node->head;
    while(_next != NULL){print; _next = _next->next}`

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Please, see my updated post about it. I suggest a different way to solve this. Let me know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Yep, seems like its working. Since we're just swapping the attributes, could we get rid of the double pointers in the `swap` function or are they still necessary? EDIT: I see you've already done this is your edit.

Comment: LOL, I have already done it :). In other words, yes we should!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to change the attributes of your cart in the swap function. The only thing that you need is a pointer to the element before the items that you want to swap.

```
void swap(cart **first, cart **ptr1, cart **ptr2){
    (*first)->next = *ptr2;
    (*ptr1)->next = (*ptr2)->next;
    (*ptr2)->next = *ptr1;
}
```

I think it works, but one should check out. If you do the swap this way, watch out at the beggining of your list.

If you don't have to sort a premade list, than you should insert the items in sorted order.